# How does the .NET application version works?

Tags: c#, .net, version

I set up a setup (installer) project in my solution and there is the version there 1.0.0.

My question is, how does the version-ing work?

What does each number mean and how does it increase? Can anyone give me an insight on how this numbering system work?

Lastly, how would I go about displaying the version number on my form?

I tried:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

But this is showing 1.0.0.0 and not the version I put into the installer (1.2).

What's the correct way to deal with version numbers?

Comment: Right click on the project->Properties->Application->Assembly Information. If it's a ClickOnce distribution (exe), the version gets updated automatically, else you have to do it manually.

Comment: what about the version number for the Installation project? is that completely different than the assembly version?

Comment: Is this a Windows Service? ...if not, why the installer? I can't speak to that.

Comment: it's a windows application. im having an installer because i need to deploy dlls and im trying to standardize everything (install package for all apps), etc.

Comment: Simple directory deploy would be fine, or zip them up. Checkout ClickOnce. Right click the root app and click 'Publish'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you are trying to retrieve with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` needs to be set in [Project Properties, Assembly Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ts8eta17%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Information about Version Numbers can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: what about the version number for the Installation project? is that completely different than the assembly version?

Comment: Each project has its own version number, including the installation project.